# convert JSON array to Ruby Hash (of hashes)

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to convert some API response data into a Ruby hash or array so I can more easily work with it. Here's the JSON string being returned by the API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "TestThing",
    "token": "B2CA27221DB976E48248F26756289B91"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "AnotherTestThing",
    "token": "EF16E5F20B8463E48DBF3BA8F0E1102A"
  }
]
```

I believe that is a JSON array? I tried doing `JSON.parse` on that string, but got `(JSON::ParserError)r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in 'parse': 746: unexpected token at '1511`

What is the best way to convert this into something I can easily work with? My real goal here is to iterate over the tokens returned.

Comment: What specifically are you showing us? What you've shown is an *actual* array of hashes.

Comment: JSON.parse _is_ usually the way to do it. What is at position `1511` in your input?

Comment: what I'm showing you is a string. It looks like an array of hashes, and I think that's what i would like it to be.

Comment: I think I must have some extra whitespace or something in my JSON. I manually trimmed it down and tried the JSON.parse and it works.

Comment: Strings have quotes around them, that's what I'm saying--it's not clear what you actually *have*. If I put quotes around this (and escape the double-quotes) `JSON.parse` works just fine.

Comment: good point. I had some floating data at the beginning of my string that made it invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question did not show the full string I was trying to `JSON.parse`. I only put what I was *trying* to parse. I accidentally left some floating data before the JSON part of my string. Now that I have deleted that, it is working.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'json'
array = '[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "TestThing",
    "token": "B2CA27221DB976E48248F26756289B91"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "AnotherTestThing",
    "token": "EF16E5F20B8463E48DBF3BA8F0E1102A"
  }
]'

JSON.parse(array)
```

Comment: You might want to run this code to see an error. What's the point of supplying a non-string object to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Yes, we need to parse it JSON.parse(array.to_s)

Comment: @AmitSuroliya But he's saying he already has a string; you're taking a Ruby array of hashes, turning it into a string, then turning it back into a Ruby array of hashes.

Comment: You might also want to run `JSON.parse(array.to_s)` to see another error.